# Querying MongoDB with List of IDs using Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, lambda

I'm hoping someone can help me:

I'm using an interface to access my data, the Find method is:

```
public IQueryable<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class, new()
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>) _db.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name, WriteConcern.Acknowledged).AsQueryable().Where(expression);
    }
```

I'm trying to build an expression to fetch all ObjectIds within a list of ObjectIds.

something like:
r => r.id.ContainsAny(List_Of_IDs); //where List_Of_IDs is of type: List

I also tried:
r => r.id.ContainsAny(new[] {id1, id2, id3}) //where id1, id2, id3 are type ObjectId

But I get an error that ContainsAny doesn't support this parameter.

I was hoping to duplicate the functionality of an IN statement in SQL. My goal is that I want the user collection to contain a list of products as a list of ObjectIds and then I want to query the products collection and get all documents in the user's list of Product IDs.

Is this possible? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much for any assistance!
Steve

BTW: here is where I send the expression to the repository method:

```
public static List<product> getByIDlist(List<ObjectId> IDs)
    {
        return (List<product>)repo.Find<product>(r => r.id.ContainsAny(IDs));       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.ContainsAny()` is only meant to be used on an array field.](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/#supported-where-clauses). So you could use it if your `.id` was an array type.

For your case you're looking for `.Contains()` or `.In()`:

```
public static List<product> getByIDlist(List<ObjectId> IDs)
{
    return (List<product>) repo.Find<product>(r => IDs.Contains(r.id);       
}
```

Which, coincidentally, is equivalent to:

```
public static List<product> getByIDlist(List<ObjectId> IDs)
{
    return (List<product>) repo.Find<product>(r => r.id.In(IDs));       
}
```

Comment: You Rock! Thanks!

I guess I need to work on writing these lambda expressions, it always seems backwards compared to SQL. - Do you think this is the fastest way to accomplish my goal of getting all the user's products? It seems like I'm trying to create relational data with a non-relational DB?

Comment: I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with your schema design. As I understand it a `User` document has an array of product IDs. The decision here is whether you want to embed (duplicate) additional product data in the `User` document, which will make updates more complex, but reduce queries to `Product` collection.

Comment: @Steve in this case it boils down to [embedding vs referencing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-decisions)

Comment: You're dead on... That's exactly my debate... I actually created a mini-product class to store popular product properties as a sub doc within the user's doc so that I don't need to run the above query often... The idea being as you said, duplicate data but less queries/data access... But I have so many years with SQL that it's hard to know & reprogram my brain to the best practices approach of NOSQL :) Thanks again for your help it's much appreciated!