# MongoDB selecting records which match value in array

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am really very new to MongoDb, I have two Mongodb documents Role and User

**ROLE**

```
{"_id":"5d0124b858d49243306deaa2",   
"mdt":"2019-06-12T16:13:44.037Z",
"mby":"000000000000000000000000",
"IsDeleted":false,
"Name":"Manager"}
```

and my another document is User with below definition and user can have multiple roles.

**USER**

```
{ 
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Doe",
  "Role" : {"5d0124b858d49243306deaa2", "6d0125b858749243306deaa2", "9b0124a852d49245306deba2"} \\ Array of role Id's assigned to users
}
```

How I can query firstName and lastName of user with matching Roles using MongoDB .Net Driver and Linq.

May sounds funny but I tried little like below

```
public List<User> GetCaseAssigneesByRoles(string roles)
        {

            return User.Query.Find(User.Query.EQ(a=>a.FirstName, roles)).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: If you're new the best idea is to find samples that do something similar to what you want to do. If you're not sure where to start, the documentation is never a bad place. Mongo's documentation is pretty good. Anyway, I usually build my queries using the filter builder, and there I would use `.In(...)`. That seems to correspond to the LINQ in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482480/querying-mongodb-with-list-of-ids-using-lambda-expression). Obviously check first/last name for equality.

Comment: @John I really shy to share what I have tried, updated question.\

Comment: You should always show what you tried, even if it's wrong. 1) It sometimes help clarify your goal, and 2) it shows that you have actually tried something yourself, and that you're not merely expecting us to do your work for you. I appreciate 2) isn't your goal, but some people do come here with that goal.

Comment: What is the contents of `string roles`? Is that the role name?

Comment: Thats _Id of Role, I know it must be passed as list but I shared what I tried

Comment: So you want a list of full names when you search for a role name (not the id)?

Comment: @Plancke Actually I have list of Role Id's based on that I want to select full name of user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to query users like so:

```
public List<User> GetCaseAssigneesByRoles(string role)
{
    return UserCollection
        .Find(Builders<User>.Filter.AnyEq(u => u.Roles, role))
        .ToEnumerable()
        .ToList();
}
```

Essentially `AnyEq` takes an array (`Roles`) and checks if any single item in the list equals the value you specify. You might have to change some of the field names in this example.

Or for a list of roles (where a **single role** has to match):

```
public List<User> GetCaseAssigneesByRoles(List<string> roles)
{
    return UserCollection
        .Find(Builders<User>.Filter.AnyIn(u => u.Roles, roles))
        .ToEnumerable()
        .ToList();
}
```

Or for a list of roles (where **all roles** have to match):

```
public List<User> GetCaseAssigneesByRoles(List<string> roles)
{
    return UserCollection
        .Find(Builders<User>.Filter.All(u => u.Roles, roles))
        .ToEnumerable()
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Will try this, Like to ask may I pass list of roles instead of role ?

Comment: @Vijay do all roles have to match in that case, or just one?

Comment: No all any roll from list match it must return user name.

Comment: OK, well choose the appropriate query and give it a whirl. Let me know if you have any problems. :-)

Comment: Sure John Thanks

Answer (score 2):

here's a simple way of doing it with LINQ using the library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) [disclaimer: i'm the author]

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class User : Entity
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string[] Roles { get; set; }
        }

        public class Role : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var managerRole = new Role { Name = "Manager" };
            var superRole = new Role { Name = "Supervisor" };

            managerRole.Save();
            superRole.Save();

            var user = new User
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                Roles = new[] { managerRole.ID, superRole.ID }
            };

            user.Save();

            var findRoles = new[] { managerRole.ID, superRole.ID };

            var managers = DB.Queryable<User>()
                             .Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => findRoles.Contains(r)))
                             .Select(u => u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)
                             .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

here's the aggregation query it sends to mongodb:

```java
db.User.aggregate([{
    "$match": {
        "Roles": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "$in": ["5d02691bada517167415c326", "5d02691cada517167415c327"]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "__fld0": {
            "$concat": ["$FirstName", " ", "$LastName"]
        },
        "_id": 0
    }
}])
```